# Python activity logging

Tags: python, logging

I have a question regarding logging for somescript.py
The script performs some actions to find matches for words the user is looking for in some pages that have become unreadable due to re-formatting and printing of the pages. 
Because of this, OCR techniques don't work for us anymore so i've come up with a script that compares countours of words to find matches.
the script looks something like:

```
import cv2
from cv2 import *
import numpy as np

method = cv.CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED

template_name = "this.png"
image_name = "3.tif"

needle = cv2.imread(template_name)
haystack = cv2.imread(image_name)

# Convert to gray:
needle_g = cv2.cvtColor(needle, cv2.CV_32FC1)
haystack_g = cv2.cvtColor(haystack, cv2.CV_32FC1)

# Attempt match
d = cv2.matchTemplate(needle_g, haystack_g, cv2.cv.CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED)


#we want the minimum squared difference
mn,_,mnLoc,_ = cv2.minMaxLoc(d)
print mnLoc

# Draw the rectangle
MPx,MPy = mnLoc

trows,tcols = needle_g.shape[:2]


#Normed methods give better results, ie matchvalue = [1,3,5], others sometimes showserrors
cv2.rectangle(haystack, (MPx,MPy),(MPx+tcols,MPy+trows),(0,0,255),2)




cv2.imshow('output',haystack)

cv2.waitKey(0)
import sys
sys.exit(0)
```

Now i want to log the various tasks that the script performs, like

- converting the image to grayscale
- attempting a match
- drawing the rectangle

I have seen a few scripts on stackoverflow explaining how to log an entire script or the entire output but i haven't found anything that just logs a few actions.

Also i would like to add the date and time the activity was performed.

Furthermore i have wrote a function that calculates an MD5 and SHA1 hash of the input file, for this particular case, that is for 'this.png' and '3.tif', I have yet to implement this piece of code but would it be easy to log that as well?

I am a python-noob so if the anwsers are obvious to you guys you know why i couldn't figure it out myself.

I hope you can help me out on this one!

Comment: Have you checked standard python logging module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html